# Why does this assert fail

Tags: c#, .net

This started because I was trying to unit test a piece of code the following way:

```
ReservationSearchParameters expectedSearchParams = new ReservationSearchParameters(),  sentSearchParameters = new ReservationSearchParameters();

List<Reservation> simpleReservationList = new List<Reservation>();

simpleReservationList.Add(........... I added data ..........)

expectedSearchParams.LocationIDs = "2";
_reservationDataLayerMock.Setup(x => x.LoadReservationsByOptionalParameters(expectedSearchParams)).Returns(simpleReservationList);

sentSearchParameters.LocationIDs = "2";
Assert.AreNotEqual(null, _reservationBL.GetReservationsByOptionalParameters(sentSearchParameters).Count);
```

My test was failing, it wasn't return what i was trying to get it to return, even though my SearchParameters data set was exact, as far as I was concerned.

So I tried this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expectedSearchParams, sentSearchParameters);
```

And it failed.  Why?

Comment: Could you provide the type definition for ReservationSearchParameters  ? Is it a struct or a class?

Comment: How did you implement Equals for  this class? Also, why don't you post real code?

Comment: AreEqual is from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.  This is real code.  I'm just testing it, trying to figure out how to mock two different search parameter objects.

Comment: I asked how you implemented `Equals` on your class. It doesn't look like real code. It doesn't appear to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ReservationSearchParameters` is `class` not a `struct` its instances are compared by references.
That's why you get false because there are two different objects with two different pointers to them and it doesn't matter that their properties have the same data.

You should write a separate assert for each property.

Comment: How can you tell that the class does not implement `Equals`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why should we assume that it does?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Why should we assume one way or the other? This answer appears to make an assumption.

Comment: Downvote because it does not cover writing an Equals implementation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Since the OP is asking why `Assert.AreNotEqual()` yields false, and neglected to provide any information about the `Equals` implementation of this class, it was a pretty good bet. And it turned out to be right.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior So what if it turned out to be right? A guess is a guess. And if you are going to guess, which is fine, say so. I don't much care for the second paragraph of this answer. It's as though `Object.Equals` doesn't exist.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It was an educated guess, which is generally necessary when people ask imperfect questions. I can buy the argument that a complete answer should *mention* `Equals`, but I actually thought the second paragraph was dead on. Implementing `Equals` for the sake of a particular unit test can have far-reaching consequences, introducing new bugs. And this test is not responsible for testing the  `Equals` implementation of the class: if it relied on the Equals implementation working a certain way, it may pass when it should really be failing.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to compare two unrelated objects that just happen to have the same values in them.

The default equality check for classes is going to be reference equality, and since these are two different objects, reference equality will fail.

In order to make the assertion pass, you need to define what makes these two objects equal.

Depending on how `Assert.AreEqual` is written, you can probably do any of the following:

1. Define the `==` and `!=` operator.
2. Override `bool Equals(object other){}` (and if you do this, it's recommended to also do `int GetHashCode()`.
3. Implement `IEquatable<ReservationSearchParameters>`.

Once you've told it how to compare two different objects, your assertion should pass.